# Bind GridView wihtout hang the UI thread

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, ui-thread

I have a problem with the UI thread, it hanging when I try to bind BindingList which contains 2,000,000 records into grid view if there any way to do that without freeze the UI please help me, or how to update some control in the UI thread without freezing?

My code:

```
    Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Await FillPositions()
        BindSource()
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub FillPositions()
        Await Execute(Function()
                          Return ExecuteFillPositions()
                      End Function)
    End Sub

    Private Function ExecuteFillPositions()
        Positions = New BindingList(Of Order)

        For index = 1 To 2000000
            Positions.Add(New Order With {
                .Id = index,
                .Comm = index * 0.123,
                .Price = index * 0.321,
                .Script = "USD",
                .Time = Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"),
                .Type = "New",
                .Value = index * 0.132
            })
        Next
        Console.WriteLine($"Source count: {Positions.Count}")
        Return 0
    End Function

    Private Async Function Execute(Of TResult)(ByVal func As Func(Of TResult)) As Task(Of TResult)
        Return Await Task.Factory.StartNew(Function()
                                               Dim result = Nothing

                                               Try
                                                   result = func()
                                               Catch ex As Exception
                                                   Throw New NotImplementedException
                                               End Try

                                               Return result
                                           End Function)
    End Function
```

The following code causes the hanging for 2-3 seconds

```
    Private Sub BindSource()
        RadGridView1.DataSource = Positions
    End Sub
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but why are you using `Task.Factory.StartNew` instead of `Task.Run`?

Comment: @Craig `Task.Factory.StartNew`, gives you the opportunity to define a lot of useful things about the thread you want to create, while `Task.Run` doesn't provide this.

Comment: Yes, and that's a good reason to do so.  I asked because the code shown doesn't do anything like that, but it's understandable to cut it out in the interest of creating an MCVE.